# CakePHP modal AJAX checks not displaying in lights out box?

Tags: ajax, cakephp

Ok, this might have a very simple answer but for the life of me my I can not seem to find an answer! I am signing up users from a text into a lights out box (SimpleModal) which AJAX loads a new page for an admin to sign up a user to a selected client list.

This all works without any issues at all, so long as the model checks are correct. I have two checks, one makes sure the username is unique and that the password has at lest 8 characters, code below. But when one or both of these checks are not meet, then the user is taken to the AJAX URL and the 'message' is then displayed. This is not what I need I need it to be taken back to the lights out box or set these messages as flash error message to be printed on to the screen.

Or should I remove these checks from the modal and get JQuery to check them instead?

Any ideas?

All help very welcome.....

Model Code ::

```
 public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('isUnique'),
                'message' => 'Sorry but a unique username is required'
            )
        ),
        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '8'),
                'message' => 'Sorry but a password of 8 characters or more is required'
            )
        ) ... more check follow but these are the issues....
```

CTP file ::

```
$this->layout = 'ajax';
$AddUserForm = $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => '/ADD-USER-URL-HERE'));
$AddUserForm .= $this->Form->input('username');
$AddUserForm .= $this->Form->input('password');
$AddUserForm .= $this->Form->input('role', array('options' => array('admin' => 'Admin', 'user' => 'User')));
$AddUserForm .= $this->Form->input('data_id', array('options' => array($data), 'empty'=>true));

$AddUserForm .= $this->Form->end(__('SAVE NEW USER')); 
echo  $AddUserForm;
```

Comment: Means it's submitting the form by reloading the page which results in closing of popup, is it so?

Comment: Yes, it seems to load the modal, at lest part way, as its seems to check if the fields are empty, but when it comes to checking the data entered into the field with what is within the database, it seems to need to reload the load. So I need to find a way to check these with the modal with ajax or something... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ctp` file

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(res) {
        $('form').replaceWith(res);
    })
})
```

can be used for validating the data using the above script,

I think this will help you for submitting the form via ajax and you can also display the error messages using the response coming from the `ajax`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: WOW!! Many thanks this code works!! I think I understand most of it but any help sites you could recommend that would break this down, as I am not sure on how it pulls the data in form the modal. This one thing in the code is the last line where .replaceWith(res) <- is the (res) bit not a var within the replaceWith call? Therefore where is that set? or am I just wrong?

Comment: sorry i'm not getting what you are trying to say.

Comment: $('form').replaceWith(res); <- this line where does the bit where res is set or is it part of jQuery?

Comment: This is the response coming from the server and it is pure html in your case. by the way this is the option for success function of `ajax` call

Comment: Sorry but how can I stop this from running when there are no error messages, as the form now reloads the whole page into the lights out box, I only want it to fire when CakePHP throws back the error-message which are the messages it returns when the user does not enter a 8 digit password or enters the same username!

Comment: I've answered your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033921/jquery-ajax-cakephp-modal-messages-into-lights-out-box-only-when-there-is-a/19043098#19043098), please check