# Jquery / AJAX / CakePHP Modal messages, into lights out box only when there is a modal error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

EDITS

This is the new code I have been working, if I have the new code outside of the check for submit, then the page does not even side in, it just goes to the new URL! but then loads the modal checks, but does all of this in a plan page as it has just loaded the AJAX file!

Glenn.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#UserSignUpUserForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    if ($('div.error-message').size() == 0) { // if no error messages 
        $('form').off('submit'); // unbind the form submission.
        $('form').submit(); // submit the form now to reload the page.
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(res) {
            $('form').replaceWith(res);
            console.log(res);
         })
    } //End of if / else check!
 })
});
```

---

OLD POST

Ok someone help me and gave me this code to solve one of my issues but now this code, once I got around to checking it out in more detail does not work 100%. I am using CakePHP and I have a user sign up for the admins, which loads into a lights out box. When the sign up modal has the meet at lest 8 letters in the password and the username has t be unique.

Now the code (which I have added to) was given to me to make sure the divs the the modal errors loaded into the lights out box. The problem is that when there are NO error the page redirect loads into the lights out box and not into the main browser window.

So I am trying to change the code below to add in a check to see when these or if these errors come back from the server, then if so fire the code, if not (if all is good) then don't do anything.

I am a little weak with JQuery, PHP being more my thing. Sorry if I have any any newbe mistakes.....

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
   var pattern = 'error-meesage'; //I added this
   var exists = pattern.test(res); //I added this

   if(exists) { //I added this
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(res) {
        $('form').replaceWith(res);
        console.log(res);
     })
   } //I added this
 })
```

This is what it gives me back, and it does not work when the errors-message divs are there, it loads them into a new window without any layout, as the request is being made by AJAX!

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Many thanks

Glenn.

---

### EDIT

If you remove the lines where I mark that 'I added this' then the code works without any problems, it has access the Jquery lib file but I think I might be stopping the layout from Cake to load all the way!!

Thanks Glenn.

---

### EDITS Code you have request is blow ::

I will also update you on the fact that I have now removed the lights out box, but what I am doing is more or less the same thing. I am now loading these pages still using AJAX into a hidden div, which then sides in using the JQuery UI side effects. But the same error happens. If there is an error, then cake reports back the error message from the modal with a div which has the class or error-message. However if there is no error message div and it saves fine, it loads the content into the div that is displayed on the side of my screen, just like it did with my lights out boxs!

However with your added extra code, it just submits the page without the user even, getting to see the whole side come in. Even to me, this should be a quick fix (just have not got around to it let, about 5 things I am working on with this site), just to check for post submit. Even though, when it does submit it loads the whole page but outside of my default layout, e.g. it is still loading it has an ajax page.

I hope that has made it clear.

This is my default layout file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<?php 
    $Header =  $this->Html->charset(); 
    $Header .= '<title>XXXXXXXX</title>';
    $Header .= $this->Html->meta('icon');
    $Header .= $this->AssetCompress->css('CssFile');
    $Header .= $this->AssetCompress->script('JSFile');
    $Header .= $this->fetch('meta');
    $Header .= $this->fetch('css');
    $Header .= $this->fetch('script');
    echo $Header;
?>
```

```
    <?php 
        $MainLayout  ='<div id="Logo">' . $this->Html->image('logo.gif', array('alt' => 'top banner')) . '</div>';
        $MainLayout .= $this->Session->flash('bad', array('element' => 'FlashError'));  
        $MainLayout .= $this->Session->flash('good', array('element' => 'FlashGood')); 
        $MainLayout .= $this->Session->flash('auth', array('element' => 'FlashError')); 
        $MainLayout .= $this->fetch('content'); 

        echo $MainLayout;
    ?> 
<div class="SideBoxUser"></div> //These are the areas where file loads!
<div class="SideBoxClient"></div>
```

The user file form ::

```
 <?php 
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    $AddUserForm = $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => '/PATH-TO-GO-TO'));
    $AddUserForm .= "<h1>Add New User</h1>";
    $AddUserForm .= $this->Form->input('username');
    $AddUserForm .= $this->Form->input('password');
    $AddUserForm .= $this->Form->input('email');
    $AddUserForm .= $this->Form->input('role', array('options' => array('user' => 'User','admin' => 'Admin')));
    $AddUserForm .= $this->Form->input('clients_id', array('options' => array($AllClients), 'empty'=>true));
    $AddUserForm .= $this->Form->submit("SAVE USER", array('class' =>'Button'));
    $AddUserForm .= $this->Form->end();
    echo  $AddUserForm;
 ?>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(res) {
        $('form').replaceWith(res);
        console.log(res);
     })
   })
 if ($('div.error-message').size() == 0) { // if no error messages 
      $('form').off('submit'); // unbind the form submission.
      $('form').submit(); // submit the form now to reload the page.
  }
 });
  </script>
```

JS file for what loads the side box ::

```
  $(".ADDUSER").click(function() {  //This is for the text link on my page
    $('.SideBoxUser').toggle("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
    $('.SideBoxUser').load('/PATH-TO-GO-TO');
  });
```

I hope that is all the code, if not, let me know....

Many thanks Glenn.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your reference to jQuery before your code. Something like this: 
`<?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); ?>`

This can typically go in your default layout.

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html

Comment: Here its in there, the error I know is that it can not seem to find the JQuery lib but you remove the lines I add (see edits in post) and it will work! I have included Jquery and all my plugins in the default layout.

Comment: I do not see where you include jQuery. Do you have it in app/webroot/js ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(res) {
        $('form').replaceWith(res);
        console.log(res);
     })
 })
```

After these lines just add this code for checking of error messages in your html as like below,

```
if ($('div.error-message').size() == 0) { // if no error messages 
    $('form').off('submit'); // unbind the form submission.
    $('form').submit(); // submit the form now to reload the page.
}
```

I've done according to my understanding, Hope this may help you.

Comment: WOW thank you so much for all your help, you really know your stuff!! However if does not work, I get the same error, Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined, when it does report back an error it loads into the whole browser window and I think its becuase its ajax, and therefore does not have any layout calls made to that file as it will be loaded back into the main layout file in Cake, which would have the Jquery. That is how I see it.

Comment: In that case is it submitting the form via ajax? if `$` isn't defined then the submitting form via also won't work in that case

Comment: But if I remove your bottom code, it works without any issues. And displays the error-message divs right where I want them but if Cake is fine with the form being submitted, e.g. that there are no error-message divs, it will work. However it loads the content of that page into the lights out box and not reloads the page.

Comment: I'm unable to find what went wrong here, can you put your view and layout code over here so that i'll try to find.

Comment: there may be a case that more forms can exist in your page, so better to access your form with some `Id`. instead of `$('form')` you can use `$('#addUserForm')` like this.